# Access to database from a Cloud Application

Tags: java, cloud

I don't have much experience in this yet but the high level question that I have is this: We have an Oracle database that our old WIN32 applications are using it to query its tables and do stuff.Now we are developing a webapp with Java, Cloud, etc...Now what are the technologies, architectures, tools, etc... available that can help me use the same Oracle tables and data this but time in the Cloud, so I can query them, show some cool graphs, update its tables, etc... Thank you very much for any help that shows me the road ...

Comment: You're developing an application to be deployed in the cloud, and you still don't know where you'll store the data? What is "the cloud" exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a little hard to follow, so I hope I am answering in the vein of what you are trying to ask.

You'd use the same tools you always use to do that stuff, the cloud is just a matter of moving some of your app to a remote server over the Internet. Assuming you are keeping the Oracle database local you would just need to set up some kind of hybrid or private cloud so that the machines can see each other over IP.  You really don't need to use different tools, just re-architect the communication layer between them.

**TL:DR** - Look up terms like [Virtual Private Cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) and [Hybrid Cloud](http://www.iland.com/solutions/hybrid-cloud). These let you have cloud resources that are (virtually) on your local network, then you just do everything the same way you normally would.

Comment: Thanks, yes Oracle database is still local. Now I should develop a Java WebApp that can also connect to this Oracle and let's say run a query and return its results to show it in that WebApp

Comment: What an excellent answer to salvage a very poorly phrased question. (Not trying to be mean to the OP. I've been there - a manager throws a buzzword out there and you have to do it. "Marketing put out fliers that say we're cloud based. When can you have that done?")

Comment: @glowcoder: Yes you described it right! :)  In the comments I descibed it a little better now . Thanks

Comment: @JohnFX: "you would just need to set up some kind of hybrid or private cloud so that the machines can see each other over IP. You really don't need to use different tools, just re-architect the communication layer between them."  ..... Yes, would you please tell me more about this, even some keyworkd I can go and Google them..much appreciated.

Comment: I added a bit to my answer to give you some direction on how to continue your research. The bottom line is that your application really isn't any different, you just set up your network so the cloud resources look local to your application.